# Okay to screw into a vinyl sash?

Tags: windows, lock, vinyl, install

My new replacement double hung vinyl window sashes were just delivered, and one is missing the locks.  There are divots but no holes.  I can reuse the locks from the old broken sash, but can I just drill holes at the divots or is there a special tool (so that I don't break the seal or crack the glass)?  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can. Depending on the screws you may not even need to pre-drill (some are self-drilling or simply small enough). If you do, keep it small--just under the screw shank diameter. Plastic deforms enough that if you go bigger you weaken the hold.